# Go-Swagger not generating properties in yaml file

Tags: go, swagger, go-swagger

I am trying to use go-swagger for generating docs but the generated swagger.yaml file doesn't have properties of a response object.

**Project Structure:**

```
cmd
   -api
       -main.go
       -movies.go
internal
    -data
       -movies.go
```

**cmd/api/movies.go**

```
//swagger:route GET /movies movies listMovies
// Returns a list of movies 
// responses: 
//  200: moviesResponse 
func (app *application) createMovieHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r*http.Request{                     
//code here 
}
// A list of movies
//swagger:response
type MoviesResponse struct {
    // All movies in system
    //
    //in: body
    Body    []data.Movie
}
```

**internal/data/movies.go**

```
type Movie struct {
ID int64 `json:"id"`
CreatedAt time.Time `json:"-"`
Title   string `json:"title"`
Year    int32 `json:"year,omitempty"`
Runtime int32 `json:"runtime,omitempty"`
Genres  []string `json:"genres,omitempty"`
Version int32 `json:"version"`
}
```

**Generated swagger.yaml**

```
paths:
    /movies:
        get:
            description: Returns a list of movies
            operationId: listMovies
            responses:
                "200":
                    $ref: '#/responses/moviesResponse'
            tags:
                - movies
responses:
    MoviesResponse:
        description: A list of movies
        schema:
            items: {}
            type: array
```

**Command (at root of project)** : `swagger generate spec -w ./cmd/api/ -o ./swagger.yaml --scan-models`

Note: I have already checked [No properties generated in json file for swagger:response](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/issues/1161) but didn't find anything which can help.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing something similar, and I think it's because my local `swagger` command was pointing to an out of date version.  You might want to try deleting your local swagger command and re-installing the latest binaries (https://goswagger.io/install.html).